# MongoDB .NET Driver - Using ElemMatch with FilterDefiniton

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to search for a time interval by `ElemMatch`. My fields of interest consist of simple objects or arrays of objects, like the following:

```
{
  "ID": "123456789",
  "field1": {
      "item1": "string",
      "item2": 123
  },
  "field2": [
      {
        "item11": 11.11,
        "myDatetime": {
           ts: 2022-10-23T23:14:55
         }
      },
      {
        "item11": 12.22,
        "myDatetime": {
           ts: 2022-08-23T23:14:55
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and my model is:

```cs
public record MongoCollection
{
    public string ID { get; init; }
    public object field1 { get; init; }

    public List<object> field2 { get; init; }
}
```

I'm trying to implement `ElemMatch` in this way:

```cs
var filter = Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.ElemMatch("field1",
  Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.And(
    Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.Gte("myDatetime.ts", fromDate),
    Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.Lte("myDatetime.ts", tillDate))
);
```

The error that I receive on this part of code is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer

I also tried this approach:

```cs
var field = new StringFieldDefinition<MongoCollection, List<object>>("field1");
```

And

```cs
FieldDefinition<MongoCollection,List<object>> field = "field1";
```

And I put the `field` in `ElemMatch` like this:

```cs
var filter = Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.ElemMatch(field,
  Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.And(
    Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.Gte("myDatetime.ts", fromDate),
    Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.Lte("myDatetime.ts", tillDate))
);
```

and I received the same error.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should refer to `field2` but not `field1`.
2. As in the `MongoCollection` class the item in `field2` is `object` type, the  filter for the nested object should be in `object` type by using `Builders<object>`.

```cs
var filter = Builders<MongoCollection>.Filter.ElemMatch("field2",
    Builders<object>.Filter.And(
        Builders<object>.Filter.Gte("myDatetime.ts", fromDate),
        Builders<object>.Filter.Lte("myDatetime.ts", tillDate))
);
```

[image]